# How to deal with a rejected edit?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, specific-edit

It seems that same kind of edition are sometime accepted and sometime rejected... Of course this depends on reviewer, weather... an so on.

I would like to understand why in this case [Two-way bit communication, RPi to RPi via GPIO](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7055252).

It's seems obvious that the question has nothing to deals with [pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pi) and is related to [raspberry-pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi), but the reviewer (the author) rejects this edition with the reason :

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

I don't know if there is only one reviewer because it comes from the author or because the reviewer has an high reputation, however the review seems wrong.

Should I try later, or give up ?

Comment: They are reviewed by human beings, so what?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the question is off-topic anyway. Looks to be more about hardware than software, note the wiring diagram in the self answer.

Comment: Not only hardware. As I understand the question, the author has a code and looks for the related wire connections.

Comment: @mpromonet: Proper wiring of hardware is not a software question, unless it's about software for wiring hardware.

Answer (score 6):

The original author of the post rejected your edit.  Regardless of what anyone really things of the edit, if the editor approves/rejects it, that action results in the suggested edit being approved or rejected outright.

While I have my reservations about the question itself, I wouldn't let this get you down.  The OP has their reasons for rejecting any suggested edit to their post.